# Face recognition software

Tags: windows, facial-recognition

I am looking for a software that can capture the face, and then lookup through all photos in a folder to compare them with the newly captured one to find similar people.

All files are JPEG and I only need a simple search to find similar faces based on look. I want to use this for a loan company to avoid clients taking loans from multiple branches of the same company because they can come up with fake IDs. So if we dedicate a folder (like passport photo format) for all active clients and when a client comes for a loan, we search his/her snapshot in that photo folder to find similar person. This way we can catch those who are using fake IDs.

Price: I'd like to see the pricing and then discuss it with management. But I hope I can find something below 1000 usd.